# jquery access value in each

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a foreach which produces a number of input boxes that hold a number of attributes such an id, quantity, color. Now, I want the user to be able to update the input quantity of all items in the foreach through a single button. I have tried using (function(index,item) to loop through the number of items that are in the foreach and post the values through ajax. Although this not seem to be working.

```
    <?php
        foreach ($allItems as $id => $items) {
          foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo'
<tr class="table_row thisismyclass">
<input class="quantity"  type="number" name="quantity" value="'.$item['quantity'].'" data-id="'.$id.'"  data-size="'.((isset($item['attributes']['size'])) ? $item['attributes']['size'] : '').'" data-price="'.((isset($item['attributes']['price'])) ? $item['attributes']['price'] : '').'"></tr>';
    }}
    ?>
```

Update button

```
   <?php
    echo'
    </div><div class="btn-updatefull">Update Cart</div>';
    ?>
```

jquery

```
    $('.btn-updatefull').on('click', function(){
    $(".thisismyclass").each(function(index,item) {

      var $btn = $(this);
      var id = $btn.parent().parent().find('.data-id').val();
      var qty = $btn.parent().parent().find('.quantity').val();
      var size = $btn.parent().parent().find('.data-size').val();
      var price = $btn.parent().parent().find('.data-price').val();
      var action = 'update';
        $.ajax ({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'mycart.php',
          data: {

            id: id,
            price:price,
            size:size,
            action:action,
            qty:qty              
          },
          success: function(data) {
   // location.reload();  
          }
        });

           });

    });
```

Comment: I feel like the issue is stemming from this line: `var $btn = $(this);` The this at that point will not be the button clicked. Since you are in the `each()` of the elements found with the class `thisismyclass`, the `this` is going to reference each of the tr rows as the each iterates over them.

Comment: Also the markup you are generating appears to be invalid.  It looks like you are trying to create a `tr` followed by a nested input, however content in a row is expected to exist in a td or a th or another of the expected child of a tr element.

Comment: Why generating multiple ajax calls? Why not just sending an array for each "product"?

Comment: ahh i've just shortened the code, it does work. I can see in my console that that mycart.php is generated to the number of items in for each. just dont get how to get the values from  tr1, tr2, tr3....

Comment: The `this` inside the each is the tr, and the input is a child of that tr.  `$('.quantity', this)` will find the quantity in the tr you are currently iterating over.

Comment: still doesnt seem to work sorry

Comment: Can you show us your updated attempt to achieve this?

Comment: i just added   (   , this)  to all the vals

Comment: i've made an example on this - https://github.com/rasselll/new.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this: on button click, iterate thru each row, and get an array of data values, and then send all the data to the server in a single request:

```js
$('.btn-updatefull').on('click', function(){
  var id = [];
  var qty = [];
  var size = [];
  var price = [];
  var action = 'update';
  $(".thisismyclass").each(function(index,item) {
    var row = $(this);
    var input = row.find('input.quantity');
    id.push(input.data('id'));
    qty.push(input.val());
    size.push(input.data('size'));
    price.push(input.data('price'));
  });
  $.ajax ({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'mycart.php',
    data: {
      id: id,
      price: price,
      size: size,
      action: action,
      qty: qty              
    },
    success: function(data) {}
  });
});
```